# Excel-VBA Delete Dynamic Range of Rows Based on Current Month

Tags: vba, excel, rows

I'm trying to create a macro that dynamically deletes a range of rows based on the current month.

The first row to be deleted contains the name of the current month. FindRow attempts to find that row, and then FindRowNumber attempts to store the that row number.

The last row to be deleted is row always 323. When I try to run this macro I always get Runtime error 91. I'm not sure what i'm doing wrong as i'm new to VBA.

The relevant worksheet for this code is always the first worksheet in the workbook.

```
Sub Delete_Rows()
    Dim Curr_Month As String
    Dim FindRow As Range
    Dim FindRowNumber As Long

    Curr_Month = MonthName(Month(Now()), False)

With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
     Set FindRow = .Range("A:A").Find(What:=Curr_Month, LookIn:=xlValues)
End With

Set FindRowNumber = FindRow.Row

Rows(FindRowNumber & ":323").EntireRow.Delete

End Sub
```

Comment: You don't need that `Set` in `Set FindRowNumber`.... `Set` assigns an object to an object variable - you have a `Long` here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BigBen has nailed it, but also worth checking first that you have found the search term, to avoid another error, and that the rows being deleted are on the correct sheet (note the extra dot).

```
Sub Delete_Rows()

Dim Curr_Month As String
Dim FindRow As Range
Dim FindRowNumber As Long

Curr_Month = MonthName(Month(Now()), False)

With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
    Set FindRow = .Range("A:A").Find(What:=Curr_Month, LookIn:=xlValues)
    If Not FindRow Is Nothing Then
        FindRowNumber = FindRow.Row
        .Rows(FindRowNumber & ":323").Delete
    End If
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: `EntireRow` is completely redundant, but I agree with the rest of the code cleanup and your comments.